# Facebook permission error problem?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I have a problem with facebook application when my applicatons still under development.

I currently have two developers both have granted permission (I mean when I see the Edit Settings under the additional permission: it does have the tick on the publish_stream, this was asked and granted during the prompted permission dialog). The strange is one of the user can publish news feed to the other one but not vice versa. When the other one publish a news feed, it gave me a permission error but he also granted the permission as well.

Does anyone has any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem .. I am using the facebook .net toolkit. The publish function need an integer user id but the user's ID is in long datatype and one of the user id haven't lost when converting so this is why I have such a strange problem